# Categorical Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov interpretation

Tags: lo.logic, ct.category-theory, reference-request

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language of intuitionistic propositional logic generated by some atomic propositions $t_1, t_2, \ldots$. The Lindenbaum–Tarski algebra of $\mathcal{L}$ can be regarded as a bicartesian closed category in which there is an arrow $p \to q$ if and only if there is a proof of $q$ assuming $p$. Unfortunately it is a somewhat dull category, as there is *at most* one arrow between any two objects.

**Question.** Is there a categorification of the Lindenbaum–Tarski algebra which enables a category-theoretic form of the Brouwer–Heyting–Kolmogorov interpretation of intuitionistic propositional logic? In particular,

- Objects should be propositions.
- Arrows should be (equivalence classes) of proofs.
- The coproduct should be disjoint, at least for the coproduct of two distinct atomic propositions.
- The terminal object should be indecomposable, so that the disjunction property is validated (i.e. an arrow $\top \to p \lor q$ is either an arrow $\top \to p$ or an arrow $\top \to q$).

It feels like the free bicartesian closed category generated by the atomic propositions is the most likely candidate, and it can be concretised by the Yoneda embedding into the presheaf topos: then we would have a genuine BHK interpretation, i.e. interpreting a proposition as the ‘set’ of its proofs. This has probably been well-studied, in which case I would appreciate any references to the literature.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43281/propositional-logic-with-categories

Answer (score 2):

I don't have it with me, and I can't recall the exact details, but I'm pretty sure Lambek & Scott's *Introduction to Higher-Order Categorical Logic* ([link](http://books.google.com/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PR5#v=onepage&q&f=false)) is what you're looking for.  In particular, they prove the equivalence between cartesian closed categories and simply-typed $\lambda$-calculi (so you get the Curry--Howard correspondence for free!).

Comment: In Part I, section 11, Lambek and Scott construct the cartesian closed category generated by a typed λ-calculus, which I can believe is what I want, except on the wrong side of the Curry–Howard isomorphism. It's not clear to me that the terminal object $\top$ is indecomposable in this category though – they only prove the disjunction property in the context of toposes and type theory later in the book, via the Freyd cover.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this paper would be good to look at:

ERIK PALMGREN (2004). A categorical version of the Brouwer–Heyting–Kolmogorov interpretation. Mathematical Structures in Computer Science, 14 , pp 57-72 doi:10.1017/S0960129503003955